# How to Access Data Within Django ManytoMany with SQL Query

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, many-to-many

I have two models in a Django site as follows, one of which is a many to many relationship:

```
class Seller(models.Model):
  account       = models.ForeignKey(Account, related_name='sellers',null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
  bio           = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
  city          = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
```

and

```
class Account(models.Model): 
  username      = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
  password      = models.CharField(max_length=64)
  name          = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

I am trying to run an SQL query on my Postgresql database, but I cannot find a clear way to to write an SQL query to access information within the many to many relationship.

I have the seller ID, and I want to get the username within Account. If I try the following, which clearly is not correct, it won't work but I'm stumped as what to do next:

```
SELECT seller_seller.bio, seller_seller.account.id
FROM seller_seller, admin_account
WHERE ...no clue!
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a common key/identifier in both models? you said you have Seller ID butt I don't think i see that in the seller class? not sure how it is structured, but generally if you have a common key you should be able to just join these tables together...? Can you post the postgresql table definitions? that would help a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get **Seller** object matching the `seller_id` you have by following query:

```
>>> seller = Seller.objects.get(pk=seller_id) # Note it would raise SellerDoesNotExists if matching pk not found
```

Then using above `seller` object you can get `username` by:

```
>>> seller.account.username
```

But problem with above query is that it does an extra query for fetching username.

So to avoid extra query you can use **select_related** which would perform **InnerJoin** with related **Account**

```
>>> from django.db.models import F
>>> seller_id = 1  # seller id that you have
>>> qs = (Seller.objects.filter(pk=seller_id).select_related('account')
                        .annotate(username=F('account__username')))
>>> print(qs.first().username)  # Note : It would raise AttributeError if no object found matching the condition.
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'm trying to do a raw SQL query of the database (using dataclips in Heroku). I can sort this out in Django, but I can't figure out how to grab data from many to many in SQL. Could you help with that? Thank you!

Comment: You can always check the raw query responsible for query result by  `print(qs.query)` in above example which basically does an inner join.